# Adding artifact to SBT sub project: Reference to undefined setting

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-module SBT project and I would like to add an artifact (generated by a custom task) to a sub module.
But I always have a `Reference to undefined setting` error:

```
Reference to undefined setting: 
  documentation/*:adocPdf from documentation/*:packagedArtifacts ((sbt.BuildExtra) Defaults.scala:1966)
```

Here is my `build.sbt` for SBT 0.13.11:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.Project.projectToRef
import sbt._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  [...]
)

lazy val adocPdf: TaskKey[File] = taskKey[File]("Generate documentation from Asciidoc")
adocPdf := {
  // generate pdf documentation to target/documentation-$version.pdf
  [...]
  file(s"${documentation.base.absolutePath}/target/documentation-${version.value}.pdf")
}

lazy val docPdfArtifact: Artifact = Artifact("documentation", "pdf", "pdf", None, Configurations.Docs :: Nil, None)

lazy val api = (project in file("api"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val documentation = (project in file("documentation"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(addArtifact(docPdfArtifact, adocPdf).settings: _*)

lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .aggregate(api, documentation)
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `addArtifact` is doing above, but you need to assign the setting that is created when you define the task body for `adocPdf : TaskKey[File]` to the given project:

```scala
lazy val adocPdf: TaskKey[File] = taskKey[File]("Generate documentation from Asciidoc")
lazy val adocPdfSetting = adocPdf := {
  //.. the task definition - return a `file`
}
lazy val documentation = (project in file("documentation"))
  //apply the setting to the project
  .settings(adocPdfSetting)
```